# Winrt - ListView Items doesn't fill all space vertically

Tags: wpf, listview, windows-runtime, winrt-xaml, listviewitem

I have the following listView:

```
 <ListView x:Name="sportList" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" SelectionChanged="sportList_SelectionChanged">
     <ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
         <Style TargetType="ListViewItem">
             <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Stretch" />                        
         </Style>
     </ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
     <ListView.ItemTemplate>
         <DataTemplate>
             <TextBlock Text="{Binding}" Margin="15,0,0,0" />
         </DataTemplate>
     </ListView.ItemTemplate>
 </ListView>
```

It produces the following Listview control:

[image]

I would like to stretch the listviewitems vertically, in order **to fill all the empty space**.
Something similar to this (achieved specifing a fixed height for the textblock)

[image]

Comment: What if you have a lot of items that it would need a scroll bar, how would you handle this?

Comment: @ChubosaurusSoftware It will have a fixed list of items

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to bind the `Height` (or `MinHeight`) of `ListViewItem` to the `ActualHeight` of the ListView. Of course we need a Converter to convert the `ActualHeight` to the equal Height for each item:

```
<ListView x:Name="sportList" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0"
          ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled" 
          ScrollViewer.CanContentScroll="False" UseLayoutRounding="True">
    <ListView.Resource> 
       <local:AutoFillHeightConverter x:Key="hc"/>
    </ListView.Resource>
    <ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
      <Style TargetType="ListViewItem">
         <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Stretch" />
         <Setter Property="MinHeight" Value="{Binding ActualHeight, 
                 RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=ListView}, 
              Converter={StaticResource hc}, ConverterParameter=win@sportList}"/>
      </Style>
    </ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
      <DataTemplate>
         <TextBlock Text="{Binding}" Margin="15,0,0,0" />
      </DataTemplate>
    </ListView.ItemTemplate>
</ListView>
```

Note that your requirement means we don't need the vertical ScrollBar. So we'd better disable or hide it. Also set `CanContentScroll` to false and `UseLayoutRounding` to true for better (more exactly set height) rendering.

Here is the `AutoFillHeightConverter` class (that we embed an instance in the ListView's Resource):

```
public class AutoFillHeightConverter : IValueConverter {
    object IValueConverter.Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter,
                                   System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        var p = parameter as string;
        var win = Application.Current.Windows.Cast<Window>()
                             .First(w => w.Name == p.Split('@')[0]);
        var lv = win.FindName(p.Split('@')[1]) as ListView;
        var lvh = Convert.ToDouble(value);            
        return lv.Items.Count == 0 ? Binding.DoNothing : (lvh / lv.Items.Count);
    }

    object IValueConverter.ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, 
                       object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

Note about the `ConverterParameter` of the Binding, we set it to a string. This string includes 2 parts separated by a `@`. The first part should be the Window's `Name`, the second part should be the ListView's `Name`. We need these Names to access the ListView instance inside the `Convert` method to convert the height.

Comment: I am gonna check it in few hours.

Comment: Sorry @King King, but i get the following errors while trying to compile AutoFillHeightConverterClass:  'FrameApp.AutoFillHeightConverter' does not implement interface member 'Windows.UI.Xaml.Data.IValueConverter.ConvertBack(object, System.Type, object, string)'
Error 2 'FrameApp.AutoFillHeightConverter' does not implement interface member 'Windows.UI.Xaml.Data.IValueConverter.Convert(object, System.Type, object, string)'
Error 3 'IValueConverter.Convert' in explicit interface declaration is not a member of interface
Error 4 'IValueConverter.ConvertBack' in explicit interface declaration..

Comment: @Duncan_McCloud well again I answered a Windows Phone question but did not know about it. However this time it may be fixed easily. The `Convert` and `ConvertBack` here (in WinRT) should have the fourth argument of type `string` (not `CultureInfo`), so you can try making that change to see if it works.

Comment: I fixed that by myself, but still compiler can't resolve "Binding.DoNothing" and Application.Current.Windows. That's maybe cause it's a Window Store (W8) app and not a Windows Phone one ?

Comment: @Duncan_McCloud yes, it could be that, sorry. I've never programmed Windows Phone. But the idea of solving your issue is the same. You can try searching for more on how to implement Converter in Windows Phone. `Binding.DoNothing` here simply means doing nothing, but if it's not existing in Windows phone, you can try using `0` (it does not matter because there is not any item). I have no idea about fixing the missing of `Application.Current.Windows`, so looks like you have to search more yourself.